# How to change column type and all foreign keys in PostgreSQL?

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm currently stuck in a catch 22 with my Django Application. I have to change the type of a column from Varying char to Integer as i'm moving from UUID's to plain old ID's (the data is not changing ever as it's physical constants). Now django threw a Fit originally about not being able to cast from VarChar to Int, so i "helped" it out with:

```
 ALTER TABLE glass_fill ALTER COLUMN id TYPE INTEGER USING CAST(id AS INT);
```

Now, it says:

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: foreign key constraint "glass_fill_manufacturer_glass_fill_id_fkey" cannot be implemented
DETAIL:  Key columns "glass_fill_id" and "id" are of incompatible types: integer and character varying.
```

Any Ideas?

Note: The glass_fill_manufacturer Table hasn't been created yet django trys to on syncdb but fails. also the,

```
ALTER TABLE glass_fill ALTER COLUMN id TYPE INTEGER USING CAST(id AS INT);
```

line didn't alter the column as I thought.

glass_fill table schema:

```
-- Table: glass_fill

-- DROP TABLE glass_fill;

CREATE TABLE glass_fill
(
  id character varying(36) NOT NULL,
  name character varying(255),
  temperature real,
  density real,
  viscosity real,
  conductivity real,
  heat_capacity real,
  colour text,
  CONSTRAINT glass_fill_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id )
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

Comment: Please post the script for `glass_fill_manufacturer`.

Comment: There is no script, It's generated by Django on the fly when I run syncdb.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```sql
ALTER TABLE glass_fill_manufacturer 
ALTER COLUMN glass_fill_id TYPE INTEGER USING CAST(glass_fill_id AS INT)
;
```

I guess by your text that Django will somehow do it but if it doesn't:

```
ALTER TABLE glass_fill_manufacturer 
drop constraint glass_fill_manufacturer_glass_fill_id_fkey
;

alter table glass_fill_manufacturer 
ADD constraint glass_fill_manufacturer_glass_fill_id_fkey 
foreign key (glass_fill_id) references glass_fill (id)
;
```

Comment: I presume that I alter my glass_fill table between those two statements?

Comment: I tried this: `ALTER TABLE glass_fill_manufacturer 
drop constraint glass_fill_manufacturer_glass_fill_id_fkey
;

ALTER TABLE glass_fill ALTER COLUMN id TYPE INTEGER USING CAST(id AS INT);

alter table glass_fill_manufacturer 
ADD table_constraint glass_fill_manufacturer_glass_fill_id_fkey 
foreign key (glass_fill_id) references glass_fill (id)
;` but I get a syntax error? `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "foreign"
LINE 9: foreign key (glass_fill_id) references glass_fill (id)`

Comment: @Jharwood I think I fixed the syntax and edited the answer. Just try the first command only.

Answer (score 1):

You should do the following:

1. Drop the constraints
2. Create a temporary table to hold mapping between old and new ids
3. Update `glass_fill`, returning the values into the temporary table
4. Update the referencing tables from the temporary table
5. Alter column types on all tables
6. Recreate the constraints

Comment: would you be able to point me towards any reference material for the above actions? I am relatively novice when it comes to PostgreSQL and I don't think I've even heard of constraints yet?

Comment: @Jharwood: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-altertable.html. Constraints in your case are `FOREIGN KEY` (search for `REFERENCES` in your tables' definitions). Are you working with someone else's code?

Comment: yes I am, I have taken over maintaining it and am in the process of updating everything